# How to place a label below a symbol in QGIS 3.18.3

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have an airport symbol and below that I want to show the label for the airport identifier.
Because I want to keep a proportional distance between the label and the symbol at different zoom levels, I used and offset as 'Meters at scale', set the symbol to be 'offset from point', on the lower quadrant, and offset 8000 on the y axis.

With zero offset on the y, the label shows over the airport symbol. With 8000 on the y it moves up. However with -8000 the label remains in the same place. It doesn't move down as I would expect.

How can I properly make the label show below the SVG symbol, and remain there at different zoom levels?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use your airport symbol in label.
In symbology choose no symbols
[image]

In labels choose single labels and in background choose your symbol and the offset beetwen text and symbol... distpatch offset beetwen text and symbol for esthetics
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this other way of placing the SVG symbol. However I ended up with the same problem.  If I do an offset in mm as in your example, it works. I can chose positive of negative values in mm and the placement will be above or below. However at different zoom levels the label ends up either too far or too close. That's why I chose 'Meters at Scale'.  For some reason, only 'Meters at Scale' will not work with negative numbers. Any value either positive or negative seems to be taken as absolute and only moves the symbol one way. The opposite way that I want..

Comment: The background option is the solution to place a symbol with a label. Then QGIS uses this fixed block according to the placement choices. I don't understand, you use  'Meters at Scale' for placement ? in version 3.16.7 I can work with negative value.